# Remote Management of Windows Server 2016 via Powershell through the firewall

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, windows-server-2016, rpc

I use a "free tier" AWS server instance.  I have only so much CPU allowance on it, and remoting to it to perform basic management stuff eats into that CPU allowance in a big way.  Enter Powershell.  I can been managing local machines with powershell for some time now, and want to employ it to manage my remote server.  The only problem however is that security is locked down pretty tightly on the remote server.  AWS security groups policies and the Windows Firewall are standing in the way.

Which ports need I open (both in AWS Security and the Windows Firewall) so that I can connect (I assume via RPC?) with Powershell?

To be clear I wish to access this server over the open internet. So:

|My Computer| => |HomeRouter| => |The Internet| => |AWS EC2 Security| => |Windows Server 2016|

Answer (score 2):

The default ports are TCP 5985 / 5986

See here for more info: https://marckean.com/2016/02/08/remote-powershell-ssl-https-5986/